# How to deserialize data in PHP which is serialized by GSON

Tags: php, android, gson

I am working on android app with api developed in `PHP`. I am trying to send an object to api, so I am serializing it with `Gson` library, and trying to deserialize in `PHP` code using `Unserialize()` function. But, its giving error as `(!)Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 468 bytes in C:\wamp64\www\digiclass\admin\api\upload_pending_results.php on line 5` and finally giving json response as `{"error":false,"data":false}` Here is my `PHP` code:

```php
<?php
//an array to display response
$response = array();
$serObject = $_POST['serObject'];
$response['error'] = false;
$response['data'] = unserialize($serObject);
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

currently, I am not performing any operation on data, rather only want to see if the data is deserializing correctly. I have tried to see the serialized object, it is converted as below.

```
%7B%22accessToken%22%3A%22b2c1f3d5e8218cfa81d23c4b9b7d6cbc20f82c67ca4b9d92be9bb7680031360a9d95bf1e3ecf42678f1c8b87a4eb5622%22%2C%22clas%22%3A%229%22%2C%22dbname%22%3A%22a_new%22%2C%22records%22%3A%5B%7B%22clas%22%3A%229%22%2C%22id%22%3A1%2C%22marks%22%3A%222%2F8%22%2C%22rollno%22%3A%2212%22%2C%22subject%22%3A%22Maths%22%2C%22temp%22%3A1%7D%2C%7B%22clas%22%3A%229%22%2C%22id%22%3A1%2C%22marks%22%3A%227%2F8%22%2C%22rollno%22%3A%2212%22%2C%22subject%22%3A%22Maths%22%2C%22temp%22%3A2%7D%2C%7B%22clas%22%3A%229%22%2C%22id%22%3A1%2C%22marks%22%3A%223%2F8%22%2C%22rollno%22%3A%2212%22%2C%22subject%22%3A%22Maths%22%2C%22temp%22%3A3%7D%2C%7B%22clas%22%3A%229%22%2C%22id%22%3A1%2C%22marks%22%3A%228%2F8%22%2C%22rollno%22%3A%2212%22%2C%22subject%22%3A%22Maths%22%2C%22temp%22%3A4%7D%5D%2C%22rollno%22%3A%2212%22%7D
```

I am not sure if the conversion is going right or what the error might be. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you are getting is a URL encode JSON string, so first decode it...

```
$serObject = urldecode($serObject);
```

and then decode it as JSON...

```
$response['data'] = json_decode($serObject, true);
```